# LATEX on Anki does not display properly; Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: ubuntu, latex, anki

Folks - I'm trying to display the basic command as below (one of many examples):

> Does the sum below converge? [latex]\begin{displaymath}\sum_{k =
>   1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\end{displaymath}[/latex]

However it produces the following error:

> Does the sum below converge? Error executing dvipng. Generated file:
>   /tmp/anki_temp/tmp.tex
>
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live
>   2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)  restricted \write18
>   enabled. entering extended mode (./tmp.tex LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch
>   level 5 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
>   Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty For
>   additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
>   (./tmp.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) [1]
>   (./tmp.aux) ) Output written on tmp.dvi (1 page, 536 bytes).
>   Transcript written on tmp.log.

I've got Ubuntu 18.10 running with Anki (Version 2.1.5 Qt 5.9.2 PyQt 5.9) and "sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra" installed.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, dvipng was missing.

Run `sudo apt-get install dvipng`

Courtesy to:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209497/anki-latex-not-working-i-have-installed-basictex-dvipng